# "Si y solo si": abreviatura más usada en español

Tags: diferencias-regionales, vocabulario-técnico, conjunciones, matemáticas, ciencia

Al igual que en la literatura inglesa se usa la conjunción *iff* para "if and only if", recogida por diccionarios como el [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iff) o el [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/iff) (y nótese que se define como conjunción y no como abreviatura), en español se usan varias conjunciones similares para "si y solo si". En textos científicos se puede encontrar las siguientes:

- *sii*: la que recuerdo haber usado yo en la carrera.
- *ssi*: la primera opción según [el artículo de la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicondicional).
- *syss*: aparentemente la menos usada.

Lo que me gustaría preguntar es: ¿cuál de estas opciones es actualmente la más usada? ¿Hay diferencias regionales en el uso de todas ellas? Y por último, ¿cuál sería la más apropiada para solicitar a la RAE su inclusión en el DLE? ¿Sería *sii* por ser la única que no contiene el grupo *ss*, muy raro en el idioma español? ¿O ya hay alguna recomendación de uso al respecto por parte de la RAE, Fundéu o similares?

Comment: Y luego estoy yo que uso "sis". Lo tomé de un amigo que la usaba en la carrera de filosofía. Pensaba que estaba más extendido.

Comment: @FGSUZ pues no te creas que es mala opción...

Comment: En la facultad de Matemáticas vi muchas veces _sii_, si bien no es algo que se recomiende demasiado porque presta a equívocos (una _i_ menos y cambia toda la secuencia lógica).

Comment: El [Diccionari de matemàtiques i estadística](https://books.google.es/books/about/Diccionari_de_matem%C3%A0tiques_i_estad%C3%ADsti.html?id=LQ5yPQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y) tiene al final una "Taula de signes, símbols i abreviatures usuals en matemàtiques". En la entrada "si, i solament si" de esta tabla se encuentran dobles flechas con tres estilos diferentes ($\Longleftrightarrow$, $\Leftrightarrow$ y $\longleftrightarrow$ en LaTeX) y `sii`.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Uso

Para hacer una comparación aproximada, buscamos al Google Scholar (es) (he incluido la frase 'si y solo si' para evitar 'positivos falsos' de nombres etc):

- [*"sii" "si y solo si"*](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22sii%22+%22si+y+solo+si%22) (997)
- [*"ssi" "si y solo si"*](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22ssi%22+%22si+y+solo+si%22) (136)
- [*"syss" "si y solo si"*](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22syss%22+%22si+y+solo+si%22) (142)

Parece que *sii* se usa más.

#### 2. Diferencias regionales

Todavía no he encontrado bastante datos para hacer tal estudio.

#### 3. La RAE

Desafortunadamente, no creo que la RAE la incluyería ninguna de estas palabras.

"Iff" es una forma de *escribir* una conjunción lógica ("if and only if", ↔), como [*xor*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/XOR) ("exclusive or", ⊻), y no una palabra que la gente 'habla'. Por su naturaleza, su pronunciación es ambigua, y no clarifica si quieres decir 'if' o iff', 'si' o 'ssi'/'sii' (*syss* puede ser una excepción aquí, pero jamás he visto ni oídolo y no parece muy popular aún).

Son palabras que solo se usan en el contexto de las matemáticas y la lógica, y aún en este contexto solo suelo *oír* la frase "if and only if" (y posiblemente *"i**ff**"*, con estrés en la efe, en situaciones poco comunes cuándo el hablante quiere contrastar *iff* con *if* explicitamente después de una confusión).

Los diccionarios ingleses son un poco más liberales en su inclusión de palabras así, pero no conozco ninguna palabra así que incluye la RAE (ni siquiera *QED*, que bien se puede hablar en conversación). Aunque no he buscado exhaustivamente - puede bien ser que sí es el caso que hay algunas palabritas similares escondidas en algún rincón.

Answer (score 1):

Como ex matemático, este uso corresponde solo a la voz inglesa *iff*, que se había mencionado; de todas maneras, esto también lo he visto en varios idiomas —en donde figuran las matemáticas— tales como italiano, francés y alemán.

El uso, sin embargo, se recoge en español como *si y solo si*; al menos, nunca lo he visto en las formas que mencionas.

Además, como es una conjunción especializada para la rama de las matemáticas, se usa, principalmente ahí y, ciertamente, en otros campos de la ciencia como física y química.